# How do actions taken affect turn order?

Tags: neptunia-v

In [Hyperdimension Neptunia Mk2, turn order changed as you performed more actions on a turn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96852/why-does-turn-order-shift); Victory seems to have a similar mechanic but not quite the same. Turn order doesn't shift until your turn is order (making it hard to tell what causes it to shift and how much), and taking some actions (items, I think, maybe SP skills?) doesn't delay your turn, but certain actions (using a full combo) does. So which actions delay turns and which don't?

I also note that some Lily Rank bonuses include "reduced wait"; does this mean the *extra* delay caused by actions is reduced, or does this effect simply mean you get turns more often period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two phases to turn order to be aware of. The system is otherwise similar to Mk2 in that every action you take accumulates a certain amount of wait, which is then weighed against how much others have in order to determine your next round of action.

At the start of combat, every single character on both sides will get at least one turn. It doesn't matter how fast anyone is, or how low of wait actions a character uses, each character gets one turn. Predictions assigned before anyone takes action, thus, do not reflect the actual turn order as future turns do. Likewise, no matter how low of a wait action you perform, you will still act after everyone else. As such, the order-of-actions isn't really accurate until everyone has taken their first action.

Afterwards, the wait system is pretty direct. Unlike Mk2, it doesn't update until afterwards, so instead it has a pretty specific wait estimation. This time is approximately the wait you get by either **using a skill** or **making a normal attack followed by a single combo attack and then cancelling**. Wait manipulation is generally done to score extra turns against an enemy, or to change the order of actions for your own characters to maximize damage dealt while the enemy is guard broken (so, moving breakers before allies but right after the enemy, or moving attackers after the breakers but before the enemy's next action).

The rough order of things is as follows, based on my own experimentation. I haven't done major stress testing so everything that takes *longer* than the predicted wait is in no particular order (aside from Combo Link).

- **Switch** has the lowest wait. If the wait is distributed right, it is possible to act with your new character immediately after switching.
- **Defend** has the next lowest wait. I wouldn't recommend this for turn manipulation as it is very easy to cut too early, getting an extra turn before the enemy (which is to say no turn since you did nothing) and then a second defend puts you in the wrong position. Stick to using this when you actually need to defend. Note that if you're **paralyzed**, the amount of wait you get per idle turn is about the same as defending.
- Doing an **Attack** and quitting right after is slightly faster than the predicted Wait. If you feel that you might be able to squeeze in an extra turn, this is a nice way to tack on some nice damage, but in most cases this is better for setting breakers in front of allies.
- As mentioned, the predicted wait is approximately the time used to either **use an SP skill** or **make an Attack and one combo attack**. If it already predicts that you'll act twice before the enemy, this is the best way to stack up on damage. For this reason, it's recommended to have a nice and strong attack at the start, definitely for Break and maybe also Power or Rush.
- **Combo attacks after the first** will cause your action to happen later than predicted, especially if you finish off with **a normal EX Finisher**. If you need someone to act after the rest of your party, this is probably the handiest sequence of wait manipulation to use.
- **Using an item** takes a bit more wait than predicted. This is extremely important to be mindful of, as it can provide a pretty significant delay.
- **Using an EXE Drive Skill** takes maybe 1.5 times as much wait as predicted. If you have extra turns before the enemy and your name isn't Blanc (see later on), save your EXE Drive skill for your later turns to maximize the damage between extra attacks and also capitalizing on guard break.
- At level 70, the major goddesses (Neptune, Plutia, Noire, Blanc, and Vert) all get **Combo Link** from the first game as a level 1 EX Finisher. This allows you to restart your combo attacks from the beginning. It also doubles your wait, and then some as you take more combo attacks. It can only be done once per turn, and can delay your action quite massively if unaccounted for.

"Shortens Wait", available as a Lily Rank bonus from some folks, an inherent trait to certain characters, and in 3 yellow Idea Chips, does exactly what it says and reduces the amount of wait that any action takes. Note that even with the maximum level of Shortens Wait, it won't make it so that you constantly act twice as fast as enemies. It will, however, generally increase the chances that you regularly get extra turns with proper wait manipulation, or mitigate the sheer delay you get from doing long actions like EXE Drive skills and Combo Link. Especially Combo Link.

One last point - I'm not entirely sure if any other attacks do this (or at least, to any similar degree), but Blanc's **Hard Break** EXE Drive adds additional wait to enemies. While it's rarely enough to allow Blanc an extra turn, it can very often setup the rest of your allies some extra actions. It also possesses some of the best Breaking power in the game, making it great for starting off boss fights or Tough Foes. If Blanc acts at the start of your party's sequence of actions, it means a nice amount of actions, but even if Blanc is late or even last, the delay can usually allow some characters to act again (as long as they didn't take long wait actions). Just remember, don't do it on the first turn after a Symbol Attack as all that extra wait is wasted since the enemy is guaranteed to act before anyone else can get a turn.